# WPF: Binding RichTextBox to Logger Output

Tags: wpf

I'm using NLog to log errors in my WPF application. The logger currently writes to a file. I've now created a `RichTextBox` and want to simultaneously write all session logs to the `RichTextBox`. I've created a wrapper over the NLog logger so I can include commands to write into some other variable in the wrapper. But how do I do the binding?

Any help is appreciated

Comment: did you think to use listview insetad ? Yoiu can bind it to an observable colelction of messages...

Comment: You want to display the contents of Nlog log into the RichTextBox. Is this correct?

Comment: I'd like to be able to format the error messages. Plus, the user will be able to copy/paste etc.

Comment: still, Felice's approach is good, it will allow implementing copy/paste/formatting even easier. Though I would propose using `ItemsControl`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would try something like this:

Create some LogReader class to deal with the read of log error, it should use a StringReader or any reader you like.
The LogReader basically will give you a string with the contents of the file. Depending your needs, and specially if the file is too big, maybe you will need to split this into chuncks, but I think you will get the idea.
Then you will have a ViewModel Class that basically presents the the data to the RichTextBox

Now comes the tricky part, but with the help of this [gem](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/WPF/wpf-richtexteditor.aspx) you will be able to do databinding of strings to the RichTextBox.

`<RichTextBox attached:RichTextboxAssistant.BoundDocument="{Binding LogMessages}"/>`

HTH

Answer (score 0):

I recently found this homemade RichTextBox target for nLog:

http://nlog.codeplex.com/workitem/6272?PendingVoteId=6272

I describe [a way to make it work here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3705480/how-can-i-use-nlogs-richtextbox-target-in-wpf-application/7709872#7709872).